# How to get the youtube channel ID and name, given a video ID

Tags: c#, php, youtube, youtube-api, windows-phone-8.1

I have a YT video id, for example: `7-7knsP2n5w`

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-7knsP2n5w)

And I need to get its channel name (in this case: **`shakiraVEVO`**) and channel id (**`UCGnjeahCJW1AF34HBmQTJ-Q`**)

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you read all of the YouTube API documentation? Surely it would mention it in there if it were possible.

Comment: What language are you coding in? Do you want to get this via JavaScript, Java, Groovy, etc...

Comment: I don't know, maybe there is some 3rd party online api...

Comment: It's a Windows phone 8.1 app, but I could also make a server-to-server request in php from an apache server

Comment: I know in groovy with XmlSlurper it would be as easy as new XmlSlurper().parse("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/7-7knsP2n5w").channelId. C# may have the same type of thing. Here might be a useful link http://www.ohloh.net/p/xmlslurper

Comment: Great, that XML file is what I was looking for. I can parse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in PHP:

```
$videoid = "7-7knsP2n5w";

$xml_video = simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$videoid);
$xml_channel = simplexml_load_file($xml_video->author->uri);

//author:
echo $xml_video->author->name;

//channel:
echo $xml_channel->link[0]["href"];
```

Comment: No longer available :(